# Возможно ли использование слова "лапидарный" в отношении элементов архитектуры?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Важно попробовать составить представление об этих ровесниках, сравнить
>   **лапидарные, низкие стены** храма Вознесения Господня в Мелешево со
>   стройной мощью пропорций церкви Михаила Архангела в Смоленске.

Только я собралась ругаться с автором, смотрю...

[lapidarius - резчик по камню](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

---

А как смотрится *стройная мощь пропорций*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Мнения**

Кстати, **лапидарность** была востребована **и в архитектуре,** и в живописи. Искусство начала XX века – яркое тому подтверждение.

http://www.topauthor.ru/lapidarniy_-_eto_chto_takoe_4266.html

Будущая живопись зовет **к лапидарному стилю,** потому что новое искусство **не выносит утонченного, оно пресытилось им**. [https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/лапидарный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

**2) С другой стороны,** этимология слова (от лат. lapidarius «**каменный**, высеченный на камне», из lapis «камень») и его многозначность может препятствовать его пониманию. Поэтому хорошо бы дополнительно использовать слова-синонимы, подходящие именно для архитектуры: ***аскетичный, лаконичный***.

**3) В качестве варианта:**

*Важно попробовать составить представление об этих ровесниках, сравнить *лапидарно-аскетичные*, низкие стены храма Вознесения Господня в Мелешево со стройной мощью пропорций церкви Михаила Архангела в Смоленске.*

Answer (score 1):

Мне такое сочетание кажется сомнительным - при сопоставлении с буквальным, этимологическим смыслом слова: (текст) *краткий настолько, чтобы **уместиться** на имеющемся **камне***. Это было о гравируемых надписях, ныне распространено на тексты и речи. То есть стены должны были где-то "уместиться"; можно попытаться обосновать "лапидарность стен" *экономией* камня ("перевернув" смысл), но к изначальному смыслу ("умещающийся текст") читателю трудно это привязать.